# Create an excel file and send it by email without save the file on the computer?

Tags: c#, excel, email, email-attachments, mailmessage

Is it possible to create an excel file and after send the file without to save it on the computer by email with attachment ?

Now I create the excel file and I save the file in my computer and after I send the mail with the file attached. It works but I want to send the file directly without saving in the disk.

I use this for the attachment

```
System.Net.Mail.Attachment attachment;
attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment("C:/Users/.......");
mail.Attachments.Add(attachment);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you will need to find a library capable of generating an Excel file.

Comment: How do you generate the Excel file?

Comment: Application xlApp = new Application();
                if (xlApp == null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Excel is not properly installed!!");
                    return;
                }
                Workbook xlWorkBook;
                Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
                object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

                xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
                xlWorkSheet = (Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

Comment: Like that using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;